# Laravel 4 printing whitespaces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, whitespace

I have an annoying bug with Laravel producing whitespace characters into my source code when I use `@extends` and `@yield`.

For example, these are the first lines of my `index.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('template.main')

@section('metas')
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
@stop
```

And my template file starts like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        @yield('metas')
```

And this is the output I get :

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

As you can see, there are six whitespace characters at the very start of the file (before the `DOCTYPE` declaration), and one before the first `meta` element.

This is not something big but I'd like to find a way to fix it. I tried everything from using spaces, tabs, eliminating blank lines... but nothing has worked so far!

Comment: You must `echo`ing that whitespace, check your controllers, routes file etc. On the 4.0.8 version I'm running that doesn't happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surelly have them (the spaces) before the calling the blade functions. I'll explin that:

Before `@extends('template.main)`, probably in a line above, you have this 6 spaces. Same apply to the `@sections('metas')` which probably has a space in the final, before you 'broke' the line.

I bet that this is the problem. I hope it helps! :D

Comment: There is no whitespaces before my blade ... It seems to be related to my DB calls, I know, it's crazy. If I delete some DB calls, the number of whitespaces go down. This is the closest I can reach to this problem :(

Comment: In that case, we had to see you query's and see if any of them is printing "ghost white spaces"